# How can I translate input use ngx-translate?

Tags: firebase, angular6, ngx-translate

```
<input type="text" name="title" [(ngModel)]="dataAdd.titleEN">
<input type="text" name="title" [(ngModel)]="dataAdd.titleFR">
```

**I need to show two title but different language**

**If I click of button en show text in English or fr show text in French**

**and save in variable string**

**Note: I need unique variable for unique data insert in Firestore**

```
    dataAdd = {
    titleEN: '',
    titleFR: '',
    }

    this.translateList = this.afs.collection('translates');
    this.translateList.doc('en').set({
    TITLE_FOR_RENT: this.dataAdd.titleEN,
    });

    this.translateList = this.afs.collection('translates');
    this.translateList.doc('fr').set({
    TITLE_FOR_RENT: this.dataAdd.titleFR,
    });
```

Comment: If i understood corectly, you want to translate user input from one language to another (english => french)?

Comment: exactly .......

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion you have assumed wrongly the usage of **ngx-translate**, this package is used in order to support multiple **pre defined languages** , for example if you want to support *en* and *fr* , **beforehand** you must have a `.json` file for each desired language, with the following **KvP structure** => where the key is a **universal key** (some string that is the same in each json file), which is **used to map values to the translations** from the `.json` files. You can check out the official [StackBlitz Demo](https://stackblitz.com/github/ngx-translate/example?file=src/assets/i18n/en.json) for detailed example of the usage.

In order to achieve the result that you described, I would suggest to use something like [Cloud Translation API](https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/) provided by Google, which is able to **translate live user inputs** (or whatever you pass to the API), after that depending on your strategy you might **display** the response from the API directly **to the client**, or load it first in the ngx-translate and then display it to the client.

## Note:

I would go for the first option, because I assume in your case filling the browser memory is unnecessary (because when loading the translation trough in **ngx-translate** you are just feeling one big js object behind the scenes)

Comment: How can I connect between  Firebase and JSON file and show input for each data  without errors or mistakes in translate .